# Best practice to deal with serialization of enum

Tags: java, serialization, enums

As we know, there will be some serialization problem when we use enum in a project, especially for deploying the code to a cluster:

Sine we can't finish deploy in a second, some deployed server could write a new item to a session, while the other may read it and occur deserialization exception.

My Question is

1. **What's the best practice to deal with such a problem?**
2. Is there a syntactic sugar or sth else for enum to be casted as `String` during runtime to avoid this. Why not?

Comment: I don't agree with the first sentence : "_As we know, there will be some serialization problem when we use enum in a project, especially for deploying the code to a cluster_", How do we know this ? Why is this a problem ? What is the link with the cluster ? You need to privode details/explanations/sources on your statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As we know, there will be some serialization problem when we use enum in a project, especially for deploying the code to a cluster:

I don't know anything of the sort.

> Since we can't finish deploy in a second, some deployed server could write a new item to a session, while the other may read it and occur deserialization exception.

That's a problem regardless of enums. Any change to a class is liable to provoke that unless well managed.

> What's the best practice to deal with such a problem?

Same as for any other class. (1) Avoid change and (2) when you can't, manage it carefully.

> Is there a syntactic sugar or sth else for enum to be casted as String during runtime to avoid this.

No.

> Why not?

I don't presume to speak for the Java authors but versioning under Serialization is already very well-defined.

If you're planning on adding values to enums maybe you should be using a database table instead.